# iOS - in a view controller, where is the most logical place to put user-session management code?

Tags: ios, ios5

I am an iOS newbie and I am trying to understand some of the "good practice" ways of doing things in an iOS app.

I have a ViewController which I made to be the controller that is called when the app starts.  In it I saw a function called viewDidLoad and I tried to modify it to check if the user has had a user_id and then call a function that would eventually make an asynchronous request to manage that user in a remote db.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    EmailUtil *email = [EmailUtil alloc];
    email = [email init];

    // This is just a test call to the function that would make a remote server request
    [email setEmail: @"test" andBody: @"hello"];


    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"user_id"] == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"First time"); 

        [standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"user_id"];      

    }
    else 
    {
        NSString *subject = @"subject";
        NSString *body = @"bod";

         NSLog(@"Not first time"); 
    }    
}
```

So there are a few things I am unsure with here. Can the fact that I am calling a function to make a remote call from viewDidLoad cause problems in that function? Currently its not sending the remote request.

Also, should I deallocate memory for the objects I create right at the end of this function?

Or should I just move this code to another spot in the class where it would make more sense to have that code there?

I call the email object like this:

```
[email setEmail: @"test" andBody: @"hello"];
```

and here is the code for the EmailUtil class:

```
//
//  EmailUtil.m
//

#import "EmailUtil.h"

@implementation EmailUtil

-(void) setEmail: (NSString *) subject andBody: (NSString *) body
{   
    NSString *final_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.my_url.com?subject=%@&body=%@",subject, body];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:final_url];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url ];

    // TODO: ok I dont really understand what this is
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {         
         NSLog(@"On return");

         NSLog(@"This is data: %@" , data);
         NSLog(@"This is response: %@" , response);
         NSLog(@"This is error: %@" , error);

         NSLog(@"OK");

     }];    


}
@end
```

Thank you!

Comment: A bit offtopic, we never write `alloc` and `init` calls in separate lines. The common idiom is `[[SomeClass alloc] init]`, anything else looks weird and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> So there are a few things I am unsure with here. Can the fact that I
>   am calling a function to make a remote call from viewDidLoad cause
>   problems in that function? Currently its not sending the remote
>   request.

Feel free to make whatever calls you want in viewDidLoad. Just make sure to not doing anything that will block the UI (e.g. some long, complicated method). Any long-running, non-UI related task would be done asynchronously in a separate queue, but that's for another day, in the distant future.

Whether you do this here, or in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, is a function of what your UI is going to do. We'd need a better sense of your app's flow to answer that question. And we need to understand what how the `EmailUtil` presents itself (often these sorts of classes use a modal presentation, which makes sense to do from another view controller and not from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`).

But, bottom line, I personally have `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` always take me to what will be the app's "main" or "home" page, and if I have something that I want to present on first time usage, but not have that be the main page, then I'll invoke this from my main view controller's `viewDidLoad`. Other guys will customize `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with the "first time used" logic. It's a matter of personal preference.

> Also, should I deallocate memory for the objects I create right at the end of this function?

The first rule of memory management is that you always should deallocate anything you own (generally anything you create) and only the things you own. But, if you're using ARC (which I highly encourage you to do), this is taken care of for you (objects are deallocated as they fall out of scope).

> Or should I just move this code to another spot in the class where it
>   would make more sense to have that code there?

Personally, I'm not crazy about having an app send an email just because the main view controller appeared, as I assume this was just an example and not a real app. But if you were contemplating putting this in a different place, the "send email" function is more logically hooked to the user tapping on a "send email" button, rather than running off and doing it itself.

On other points:

1. This code is curious, though, because you're creating `EmailUtil`, a local var, setting setting some its properties, but then not doing anything with it, and then letting it fall out of scope. I presume you'd want some method to make this `EmailUtil` do its stuff, e.g. `[email sendMessage]`, or whatever the appropriate method is.
2. You're also creating two local vars, `subject` and `body`, and not using them and letting them fall out of scope. I presume you wanted to update your `email` object's properties accordingly but have not gotten to that.
3. Is there a reason you're writing your own `EmailUtil` class rather than using [`MessageUI.framework`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MessageUI_Framework_Reference/_index.html)? Hopefully `EmailUtil` is just a nice wrapper for the `MessageUI.framework`, or doing something completely different, but not replicating functionality that Apple already provides.
4. You said that the app will "make an asynchronous request to manage that user in a remote db". Wow. I do that sort of stuff all the time, now, but I wouldn't suggest asynchronous coordination with a server as a good first-time project. Hopefully when you said "eventually" you meant "a couple of months from now" and not "in the next week or two." Looks like you're still getting your sea legs on basic view controller and memory management stuff. You might want to see if you can constrain the functionality of your initial version of the app to something a little less ambitious. If you don't have some basic skills yet and try to do something complicated, you can end up with a real mess on your hands that you'll find yourself completely rewriting later. So, no offense, but see if you can come up with something a little simpler for your first real project. Or do a couple of test apps first. Just a thought.
5. Lvsti is quite right that the typical object creation construct is `[[EmailUtil alloc] init]`. What you have is equivalent, but non-standard.
6. I know it's a work in progress, but it looks like your `setEmail:andBody:` is setting properties and sending the message. I'd suggest (a) having `@property` entries for `subject` and `body` (which will automatically generate `setSubject` and `setBody` methods, as well as let you do stuff like `email.subject = @"This is the subject of the email";`); (b) if you want, have an init convenience method, e.g., `initWithSubject:body:` which will do the init your object and set these two properties; and (c) have a separate method that actually sends the message. It's not a good practice to have something that looks like a setter, is sort of a setter, but also does more material stuff, all in a single method. Methods that begin with the word "set" are generally standard setters and iOS conventions will lead other programmers to misread your code (as I just did). By following some standard iOS conventions, it will be easier if you ever get iOS programmers involved in reviewing and revising code.

Comment: thank you for explaining everything in such a detailed way.  Let me clarify a bit what I am doing.  I already have an Android app and I am just trying to make the same app in iOS now :) The use of EmailUtil is to email me :) ....I use it with lots of success to help me monitor user behavior on the app and improve the app from those alerts.

Comment: The reason I want to make remote calls when the app loads is so I can make a new user record for this download. Doing this in my Android app helped me not make people create accounts, and greatly improved conversion and engagement.

Comment: btw your profile says you are in NYC. I am also. What is your email? Maybe we can chat about our projects since in your profile you noted that you are an entrepreneur.

Comment: I just updated my original question to show how I am using the EmailUtil class

Comment: Ah, ok, I get what you're doing. Makes sense. Personally, I'd lean towards an "opt in" sort of policy with some UI that discloses to the user what you're doing. Not disclosing and doing it behind the scenes would generally be frowned upon.

Comment: I've updated my answer to discuss some conventions regarding your `EmailUtil` class.

Comment: thank you for your advice...I am definitely trying to learn the good-practice conventions....just I am pretty new to iOS so it will take a bit of time before I get them all right.  By the way, just so I am clear, the viewDidLoad seems NOT to be the best place in the controller to call the Email function.  But maybe I missed it, but where inside that controller is the better place to call it? I will need to be calling it from a number of different controllers.

Comment: And yeah, I have been thinking how to be more transparent with the sending of emails, but its internal analytics data I am sending. I think every company tracks internal user behavior (if they don't they should) so I am not sure if I am crossing any lines there....although I do see how it might be weird for users :)

Comment: I think the main controllers `viewDidLoad` is an acceptable place to initiate these tasks. `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is fine, too (though I personally don't like putting too much logic in the app delegate, I constrain it to setting up and launching the first controller and app start and stop logic, but you could make an argument for putting). You can make arguments for both and it probably doesn't matter too much. For you main view controller's `viewDidLoad`, though, you should probably be aware that this can be called multiple times (in particular low memory situations).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14082/discussion-between-robert-ryan-and-geekedout)

Answer (score 1):

You should move this code to the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of your appdelegate. 
From iOS-Dev-Center

> You should use this method to initialize your application and prepare
>   it for running. It is called after your application has been launched
>   and its main nib file has been loaded. At the time this method is
>   called, your application is in the inactive state.

And if you are not using arc, only thing you should release is EmailUtil, no reason to deallocate something by hand

Comment: Thank you, one thing though - this kind of session-management code will be different to each controller.  So where in the individual controllers should I place this code? I think the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is global in the app, right?

Comment: i think @Robert-Ryan explained that very well